# Show Desktop Ctrl-Alt-D stopped working for Firefox only. Why? How to fix?

Tags: firefox

I don't know why but

show Desktop Ctrl-Alt-D suddenly stopped working for Firefox only (in all workspaces).

Any ideas what might have caused this?

Thank you all!

ps:
alt-space-n or ctrl-alt-arrow_key both continue to function normally (as a quick and effective work-around).

pps:
in keyconfig I can't see any addon using this combination; plus, I did not install a new addon recently...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***not*** solved, after all (problem re-appeared).

Thought yesterday's update (of Firefox and the firefox-globalmenu (unity appmenu integration for FF)) had resolved it. The firefox-globalmenu (unity appmenu integration for FF) was the only thing which I changed recently in FF, so I thought that probably was the cause of the malfunction.

So now, in the same session, suddenly (after some switching between workstations) the problem reappeared.

:(

Comment: now it works again (same "session", not even interrupted by a standby). I don't know what changed.

Answer (score 1):

For me, Super ("Windows") + D works.

Comment: I'm on a Thinkpad (X41); hence, there's no Windows key, and no super key (by default) either.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it Super+D? To **Show Desktop** Ctrl+Alt+D is never a Default shortcut in Ubuntu. However if you have changed it just go to 'Keyboard Shortcuts' which you will find under 'Themes and Tweaks'

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-D does work for all applications _except_ for **Firefox** (this behaviour started 2-3 days ago).

Comment: I assume that adding a 2nd shortcut to "show desktop" would also work for Firefox. But the thing is: I don't want an extra individual shortcut. The two work-arounds cited above (alt-space-n or ctrl-alt-arrow_key) work already. I just don't know why FF is playing up. Could some extension suddenly have usurped that keyboard shortcut combination? But if so, which?!?